# How to parse timestamp in Spark 3.0 without a Parser Time Error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a column with timestamp values:

| ts_values |
| --- |
| 1682121600 |
| 1693180800 |

The ts_values column is LongType() data type.

When I try to run this code

```
max_ts = df.select(F.max(col("ts_values")).collect()[0][0]
```

I got the error

```
An error occurred while calling o472.showString. Text '2023-04-22 00:00:00' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 10
```

I know that if set up the spark configuration **spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy", "LEGACY")** it will work but I would like to understand how to get it in a correct way in code.
This code worked in Spark 2.4.6

Do you know how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First convert the ts_values then use collect to get max Date.

Timestamp conversion of
function from_unixtime can be sued in columns of df

CODE INPUT:-

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, max, from_unixtime

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("TimestampHandling").getOrCreate()

data = [
    [1682121600],
    [1693180800]
]

columns = ["ts_values"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
df.show()

max_ts=df.withColumn(
    "date", from_unixtime("ts_values"))


max_ts.show()

print("then use collect()")
max_ts = max_ts.select(max(col("date"))).collect()[0][0]
print(max_ts)
```

OUTPUT:-

```
+----------+
| ts_values|
+----------+
|1682121600|
|1693180800|
+----------+

+----------+-------------------+
| ts_values|               date|
+----------+-------------------+
|1682121600|2023-04-22 00:00:00|
|1693180800|2023-08-28 00:00:00|
+----------+-------------------+

then use collect()
2023-08-28 00:00:00
```